# Python - Convert dataframe elements to np.arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe df3 with one column that has the following format:

```
df3
Out[196]: 
                                              Utterances
0                   23825 141520 79229147 135 1951822935
1                                       15162091514 2015
2                                      1851315229147 114
3                                  225189625 141135 1144
4                                    1325 31854920 31184
5                                         31854920 31184
6           2085185-5719 19151352089147 1514 1325 229191
7      2085185 919 114 11618 129115 2015 3151329145 2...
8      185351420 193113 21815115 9142015 1325 3151316...
9      851216 2015 7520 1325 6152118 8211441854 41512...
10                                     31143512 15184518
11                                     31143512 15184518
12                                 13315211420 172151825
13                                                229191
14                                        16518191514112
15     9 15235 1514 19516205132518 20235142025 149142...
16     9 14554 2015 69144 152120 2385185 1325 14523 3...
```

What I need is to create a numpy array arr that will have the following format:

```
array=[[23825, 141520, 79229147, 135, 1951822935], [15162091514, 2015], [1851315229147, 114], [.....]]
```

Moreover, the approach: df3.values will not work, since the output is the following:

```
array([['23825 141520 79229147 135 1951822935'],
       ['15162091514 2015'],
       ['1851315229147 114'],
       [....]],
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: just did, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
In [5639]: np.array(map(str.split, df.Utterances.values))
Out[5639]:
array([['23825', '141520', '79229147', '135', '1951822935'],
       ['15162091514', '2015'], ['1851315229147', '114'],
       ['225189625', '141135', '1144'], ['1325', '31854920', '31184'],
       ['31854920', '31184'],
       ['2085185-5719', '19151352089147', '1514', '1325', '229191'],
       ['2085185', '919', '114', '11618', '129115', '2015', '3151329145', '2'],
       ['185351420', '193113', '21815115', '9142015', '1325', '3151316'],
       ['851216', '2015', '7520', '1325', '6152118', '8211441854', '41512'],
       ['31143512', '15184518'], ['31143512', '15184518'],
       ['13315211420', '172151825'], ['229191'], ['16518191514112'],
       ['9', '15235', '1514', '19516205132518', '20235142025', '149142'],
       ['9', '14554', '2015', '69144', '152120', '2385185', '1325', '14523', '3']], 
       dtype=object)
```

Or,

```
In [5642]: np.array([x.split() for x in df.Utterances.values])
Out[5642]:
array([['23825', '141520', '79229147', '135', '1951822935'],
       ['15162091514', '2015'], ['1851315229147', '114'],
       ['225189625', '141135', '1144'], ['1325', '31854920', '31184'],
       ['31854920', '31184'],
       ['2085185-5719', '19151352089147', '1514', '1325', '229191'],
       ['2085185', '919', '114', '11618', '129115', '2015', '3151329145', '2'],
       ['185351420', '193113', '21815115', '9142015', '1325', '3151316'],
       ['851216', '2015', '7520', '1325', '6152118', '8211441854', '41512'],
       ['31143512', '15184518'], ['31143512', '15184518'],
       ['13315211420', '172151825'], ['229191'], ['16518191514112'],
       ['9', '15235', '1514', '19516205132518', '20235142025', '149142'],
       ['9', '14554', '2015', '69144', '152120', '2385185', '1325', '14523', '3']], 
       dtype=object)
```

Comment: None of them work. When I am trying to fit a k-means model with these arrays, I get back: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @user37143, the above solution produces arrays whose entries are of type `str`. The solution will need to be modified to cast them to a numeric type.

Comment: Ah, but there is a `2085185-5719` in one the rows, may not work.

Comment: OK, suppose I clean all the "-..." from the data, how would you go with it then?

Comment: If `df` is clean, `np.array([[int(v) for v in x.split()] for x in df.Utterances.values])`

Comment: Or, `np.array([map(int, x.split()) for x in df.Utterances.values])`